# Giving myself permission to edit files with a text editor on var/www/drupal

Tags: permissions

I'm very new to Linux and Ubuntu. I just installed a Drupal site locally on my machine for development purposes only. However, the only way I seem to be able to edit files is by running 'sudo nano '. That's really a pain. I'd like to be able to just open files in gdedit (for example) and edit and save them there.

I have drupal installed in a directory on /var/www that we'll call 'drupal'. It has tons of directories and files inside. I need to be able to give myself access to edit anything in there.

How can I give myself permissions to edit files in my drupal site at /var/www/drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the File/Fodder Permissions

Change File/fodder Permissions by
Opening up a Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd>Type in

```
sudo chmod ugo+wrx /var/www/drupal/ -Rf
```

More on [File Permissions Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

Comment: I appreciate your help. This seems like what I was looking for.  It scares me though because I'm so new to all this. Can you explain what the parts of the command do? (note: i know what sudo chmod and my file path are, its the ugo+wrx and -Rf parts that frighten me).

Comment: u = owner  g =   group u= other  + = add permission r = read w = write x = execute.  -Rf will apply the changes to all sub fodders and files. now that I think about it you don't need to add the execute permission. here is a link if you want to know more about permissions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: thank you for the explanation - it helps me learn. And your suggestion worked by the way, so thanks again for that!